# Tensorflow DNNRegressor predict_score output

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to run DNNRegressor on some simple data so i can test its accuracy, the model should take any bank transaction and try to predict its price, But i am getting some weird results which I think is a result of something wrong with the code.

My code is here:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import absolute_import

import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

print('Running version of tensorflow')
print(tf.__version__)

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.DEBUG)

names = [
    'trans',
    'price',
]

predict_names = [
    'trans'
]

dtypes = {
    'trans': str,
    'price': np.float32,
}

df = pd.read_csv('simple.csv', names=names, dtype=dtypes, na_values='?')

# Split the data into a training set and an eval set.
training_data = df[:50]
eval_data = df[50:]
print("Training with this :\n")
print(training_data)

# Separate input features from labels
training_label = training_data.pop('price')
eval_label = eval_data.pop('price')

# Feature Columns
training_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=training_data, y=training_label, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None)

eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=eval_data, y=eval_label, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_epochs=None)

#Embed the column since its a string
transformed_trans = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('trans', 50)
print("Transformed words **********************")
print(transformed_trans)

dnn_features = [tf.feature_column.indicator_column(transformed_trans)]
# regressor = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=[trans])

dnnregressor = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=dnn_features, hidden_units=[50, 30, 10])

#train the model
dnnregressor.fit(input_fn=training_input_fn, steps=1)

# Evaluate the trianing
dnnregressor.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=1)




# Predictions
predictdf = pd.read_csv('simple_predict.csv', names=names, dtype=dtypes, na_values='?')
predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=predictdf,shuffle=False, num_epochs=1)

print("Predicting scores **********************")


y = dnnregressor.predict_scores(input_fn=predict_input_fn)
for x in y:
    print(str(x)+"\n")
```

My data looks like this

```
simple.csv:

Uber,4
Food,12
Coffee,4
Cafe,10
Coffee,4
Cafe,10
Uber,4
Food,12
Coffee,4
Cafe,10
Coffee,4
Cafe,10
Uber,4
Food,12
Coffee,4
Cafe,10
Coffee,4


simple_predict.csv:

Uber
Food
```

I would assume that with the following data set that is fairly predictable i will get 0 loss and the predictions will be on point.
But its not the case at all, I am always getting a prediction for Uber and Food that are exactly the same and i cannot even understand the results that im getting.

Am i missing anything in the code? or have i miss understood how the DNNRegressor should work anyways?

Comment: Could be a hashing issue? Maybe try `categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list` and `embedding_column`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the above code was that the hashing rate was too low.
So by simply bumping that hashing rate to 300 rather than 50 it will then all work.

```
transformed_trans = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('trans', 300)
```